# How to take struct as a reference to function?

Tags: c++, struct, reference

I have the following struct:

```
struct pole{
    int sifra;              // sifra na artiklot
    string opis;            // opis na artiklot
    float cena;             // edinecna cena
    int vlez_kol;           // vlezna kolicina
    int izlez_kol;          // izlezna kolicina
    float dan_stapka;       // danocna stapka
    float iznos;            // iznos
    int datum;              // datum na vlez i izlez (GGMMDD)
};                          // maksimalen broj na artikli e 100

pole artikli[100];


void vlez_artikl(artikli[]){ // how to take the struct as reference?

}
```

And I'm writing a function to input elements for each element in the struct, but I don't know how to take the struct (by struct I mean the `pole artikli[100]` as a reference to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void vlez_artikl(pole &artikli){

}

//later you can call

vlez_artikl(artikli[32]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that worked, but only if the struct is global and visible for both function and main()

Comment: @user2699298 No, the object only need to be visible at the place you _call_ `vlez_artikl()`. There is no need to make it global.

Comment: when I do that, it tells me they're not declared. When it's global, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass the array of structs?  If not, then timrau's answer is appropriate.

To use a reference, you need to have the function know the exact type referred to, including the array dimension.  This is only possible with a template:

```
template <size_t N>
void vlez_artikl(pole (artikli&)[N]) { // take the struct[] by reference
    ....
}
```

As using templates has downsides (a template instantiation per N, N must be known at compile time, the template implementation must be exposed to the translation unit using it), it's far more common to write functions that access an array using a pointer (often with the array size passed alongside).  Both the following are equivalent....

```
void vlez_artikl(pole artikli[], size_t n) ...;
void vlez_artikl(pole* artikli, size_t n) ...;
```

Comment: I'm using it for arrays, yes and timrau's method works well, except that I can't use the index of arrays inside the function, so I have to use it outside the function. Is that supposed to work that way?

Comment: Well, timrau thought you wanted your function to work on a single structure from the array, whereas I'm assuming you want the function to have access to the entire array.  Take your pick ;-).

Comment: It gives a lot of errors when I try to use this method, I already tried it. So I gave up pretty much, but I'd love to get it fixed, it would make the program code easier to read and way better. May I ask, is it required to have the size of the array passed?

Comment: If you edit your question and put your code there, I may be able to help explain your issues.  For the template version you don't need to specify the size - the compiler will work it out (but it must be a compile-time constant).  For the other versions you must specify the size.

Comment: when I specify the size, do I have to use all the elements of the array?

Comment: No... it's possible to call using a value of `n` less than the array size, or you can even start at another position in the array as in: `vlez_artikl(&artikli[6], 10)` to operate on `artikli[6]`..`[15]`.

Comment: Ok, well, I'll update the code and if I have any troubles, I'll post the code later. Thank you!